# Part of RegExp pattern from variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a newbie in regular expressions. I have a problem with this one. I need to add chars from *addons* variable as allowed characters to the next regex *re*.

```
var addons = '_-';
re = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/i);

console.log('match a', re.test('a'));
console.log('match a_', re.test('a_'));
console.log('no match 9', re.test('9'));
console.log('no match 9_', re.test('9_'));
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are the `addons` characters only allowed at the end? Or in any position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the regex allowing those characters too:

```
var addons = '_-';
    re = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]+['+addons+']?$','i');

console.log('match a', re.test('a'));
console.log('match a_', re.test('a_'));
console.log('no match 9', re.test('9'));
console.log('no match 9_', re.test('9_'));
```

That will test for any of the characters in `addons` (the brackets), and they're not required (the `?`).